# How to slice dataframe based on increment of value in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
frame = pd.Series([4051, 4052, 4053, 4054, 4060, 4061])
heat = pd.Series([52, 51, 50, 52, 53, 50])
df_1 = pd.DataFrame()
df_1['Frame'] = frame
df_1['Heat'] = heat
```

I have a dataframe `df_1`. I want to retrieve a dataframe `df_2` which only contains the rows of `df_1`, whose increment of `Frame` from one row to the next is smaller or equal to 3. If the increment is larger, the search shall stop.
I tried this:

```
i = 0
df_2 = pd.DataFrame()

for i in df_1['Frame']:
    j = i+1
    if (df_1['Frame'][j] - df_1['Frame'][i]) > 3:
        break
    else: 
        df_2.append(i)
```

It results in an error. Can you find my mistake? If possible, I would prefer a solution without a loop since loops tend to be slow.

My desired output would be:

```
frame = pd.Series([4051, 4052, 4053, 4054])
heat = pd.Series([52, 51, 50, 52])
df_1 = pd.DataFrame()
df_1['Frame'] = frame
df_1['Heat'] = heat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) with compare for greater and mask by [`Series.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html) for filtering in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with invert mask by `~` for bitwise `NOT`:

```
df_1 = df_1[~df_1['Frame'].diff().gt(3).cummax()]
print (df_1)
   Frame  Heat
0   4051    52
1   4052    51
2   4053    50
3   4054    52
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain what difference .cummax() makes? I get different outputs for using / not using it. I do not understand the documentation of .cummax().

Comment: @lonyen11 - it create `True`s from first match condition to end of rows, check difference  print (df_1['Frame'].diff().gt(3)) and `print(df_1['Frame'].diff().gt(3).cummax())`